# GhostScript: gswin32c hangs, but gswin32 works

Tags: java, ghostscript

We are busy converting PDF files to TIFF files using GhostScript 9.06 using the following command:

`gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiff24nc -r300 -sCompression=lzw -sOutputFile="C:/destination.tif" "C:/source.pdf" -c quit`

This is executed via Java on a Windows server that runs most of our batch tools.

This works great for a large part of our files, but for some files, the process just hangs and the task manager shows that the gswin32c.exe process is using 0% of the CPU. We have already resorted to killing the process after a minute and convert the PDF using PDFBox instead if GhostScript fails to respond.

When using the same command, but with the `gswin32` tool, the conversion works perfectly, minus the fact that it opens and closes a GUI window each time the command is executed. Because of this, using `gswin32` is not an option because people are working on the server constantly.

Comment: When I tried your command with a simple .ps file, it ran fine on my machine with 9.0.4 and no hang. Try cutting the problem down. Try it with a different .pdf file or a simple .ps file. Rather than -r300, try -r72. Try it without the -sCompression. Try it with a different device than tiff24nc. copy the .pdf to the gsbin directory and just run the file source.pdf rather than the quoted "c:/source.pdf" and the same for the destination and run the command directly in the dos directory. try just running gswin32c source.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of '-c quit' add -dBATCH to the command line. Unless your PDF files are all single pages, you probably want to add a '%d' to the output filename too.

Comment: According to the GS document, dBATCH is equivalent to putting -c quit at the end of the command line. We also want to have each pdf converted to a single tiff file. Anyways, I tried your suggestion and the process still hangs.

Comment: Well if you can supply a file to look at you can open it as a bug report at http://bugs.ghostscript.com I can't really say anything more without seeing a problem file. I still wouldn't use '-c quit' because that's PostScript and you are executing a PDF file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately the documents we are converting are legal documents and we are not authorized to share these (or even open them). As temporary solution now we start the `gswin32` process minimized.

Comment: Perhaps you can ask someone to create a safe file using the same process, and share that. To be honest I can't see any way that tihs should happen, because the two applications are practically identical.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has nothing to do with Ghostscript. You will get the problem with every programm that you run with ProcessBuilder which sends output to Standard out. As Windows buffer only limited amount of text, when you do not read the output in your java programm the called process will hang. So you can run gswin32c successfully when your conversion to pdf will only produce a small amount of status messages. But when you convert a file with many pages the process will hang. The solution is to read the output of the called process in your Java program.

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gs\\gs9.10\\bin\\gswin32c.exe", "-sDEVICE=\"pdfwrite\"",
    "-dNOPAUSE", "-dBATCH", "-dSAFER", "-dQUIET", "-sOUTPUTFILE=\"" + fileName + ".pdf\"", "\""
    + fileName + ".ps\"");
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true); //Redirect Error Stream to Standard Inputstream so that we have to read only Standard in
Process process = processBuilder.start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
rd.close();
process.waitFor();
```